# Virtual camera device on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: gpu-driver, camera

I'd like to be able to use a virtual camera device with OBS studio to combine several outputs in a non-streaming application such as Zoom/Meet/Bigbluebutton.

I've followed tutorials for v4l2loopback and they don't seem to work on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 20 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases, but your question seems to be more a standard *yy.mm* release not a *yy* release.

Comment: @guiverc Fixed that